# how to make asynchronous Mutable request and getting only last request value and canceling all request before last request

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsjsonserialization

```
NSError *error   = nil;


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSOperationQueue *downloadOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[downloadOperationQueue cancelAllOperations];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Url]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Respose %@",response.URL);
     NSString *jsonInString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"json in string for backend: %@",jsonInString);

     [self.delegate responseConnection:data withMethodName:methodName];
     if (!error)
     {
         // did finish logic here, then tell the caller you are done with success
         // completion(YES, nil);
     }
     else
     {
         // otherwise, you are done with an error
         //  completion(NO, error);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Why don't you use `NSURLSession`?

Comment: yes I have that piece of code but will you tell me to get that with bellow code:

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{


if (error)
                        {
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                        } 
}];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `NSURLSession`:

You can use   `[NSURLSession cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];`

For `NSURLConnection` also

You can use   `[NSURLConnection cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];`